# Can it be done using UIAnimation?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I am developing a game for iPhone and I came across a question whether this can be done using UIAnimation or I have to switch to OpenGL.

[image]

If you see the picture above, you can realize there is a rectangle (it will have background image) having many holes in it. User is supposed to touch on holes and initiate the animation. The holes are actually on the image and are not some view. Do you know any article or tutorial I need to read in order to understand this can be done using UIAnimation?

It's more like chess. When you tap a hole, there is a view placed and moved at z-axis and then when you press the other hole, the view is moved to that hole and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it can be done with `UIView`s too. The holes can be made by using an image with "transparent" holes in it. You can place this `UIView` on top of a background image(if required). When touches are detected, you can animate another view on top of this view using `addSubview:`. You can keep this other view outside the screen bounds initially so that the animation seems like a sliding animation.

Comment: I think so, yes. check out this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html). You'll have to go through the concepts of anchorPoint and 3DTransforms

Comment: I will look into it and tell you then.

Answer (score 0):

yes UIView is also an option in your case. if you feel that you will use high quality lots of graphic and will do lots of animation stuff at once on the screen, openGL will be the best or perhaps the gane you are making is a 2d game so you must consider COCOS2D "http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/" for kick starting your game you'll surely get many effects and other glittering stuff with it. and bes of all it is openGL based..!! Performance will be too high for you..!!

Best of luck..!!